# JetBrains DataSpell debugging

Tags: python, debugging, dataspell

I'm developing code to analyze data with JetBrains DataSpell, using Python.
I created a Python environment for using inside DataSpell with Anaconda and set it as working environment inside DataSpell.

[image]

When I try to debug code inside DataSpell I got this error message:

> Connection to Python debugger failed: No connection (command:  501 )

Any suggestion?